# Aplicando Migrations em Tempo de Execução .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

A pergunta é exatamente como no título deste tópico, porém toda ajuda que encontrei relacionada ao assunto está executando o código no startup da aplicação exigindo que seja passados argumentos para o host.

Gostaria de executar os migrations em um método da minha controller após o login do usuário no sistema pois possuo um esquema de Multi Tenant onde trabalho com vários bancos e direciono o usuário pro seu banco após o login mudando a Connection String em memória.

Referências:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090881/migrating-at-runtime-with-entity-framework-core
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Código encontrado para colocar no startup:

```js
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Wire up whatever your equivalent DbContext class is here
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

Meu método de Login:

```js
 public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginVm)
{
            Constants.ConnectionString = config.GetConnectionString("ConnString_Generica").Replace("[CLIENTE]", loginVm.Cnpj);

            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                loginVm.MessageValidation = Resources.Resources.TentativaInvalida;
                return View(loginVm);
            }
            
            ///Após isso aplicar os migrations
}
```

Comment: Você não consegue instanciar a `DbMigrator` e executar o método de update? Ou até mesmo direto pelo `ApplicationDbContext`?

Answer (score 0):

Se você já está fazendo a injeção de `ApplicationDbContext` no container de injeção de dependências por meio do `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()` dentro de `ConfigureServices`, você pode recebê-lo no construtor do controller:

```
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public LoginController(
        ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = applicationDbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginVm)
    {
        Constants.ConnectionString = config.GetConnectionString("ConnString_Generica").Replace("[CLIENTE]", loginVm.Cnpj);

        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            loginVm.MessageValidation = Resources.Resources.TentativaInvalida;
            return View(loginVm);
        }

        _dbContext.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

conforme mostrado acima, você conseguiria aplicar a migration dentro do controller: `_dbContext.Database.Migrate()`